# Testng rerun ignored tests

Tags: java, testng

I want to rerun failed tests using testng, so I have the following testng.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suit1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="PackageName.AnnotationTransformer"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="all-tests">
         <packages>
             <package name="PackageName"/>
         </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Annotation transformer class:

```
public class AnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(MyRetryAnalyzer.class);
    }
}
```

The problem is testng runs the following test even though it has Ignore annotation:

```
@Test
@Ignore
public void testRetry() {
    System.out.println("enter here");
}
```

RetryAnalyzer class:

```
public class MyRetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int retryCount = 1;
    private static final int maxRetryCount = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        if(retryCount <= maxRetryCount) {
            System.out.println("retry test "+iTestResult.getName());
            retryCount++;
            return true;
       }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Why testng runs the ignored tests?

Answer (score 1):

[@Ignore](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) should be on class or package and **not** on method

> TestNG lets you ignore all the @Test methods :
>
> - In a class (or)
> - In a particular package (or)
> - In a package and all of its child packages

You can add `@Test(enabled=false)` to method so it will be ignored

Comment: Thank you for the response. It solved the issue when I add enabled=false. But when I put ignore on class it still runs the test

Comment: import org.testng.annotations.Ignore; I didn't understand the second question

Comment: Still Ignore class doesn't work. Testng Ignore the class only the first time and not on the retry. Any ideas?

Comment: @Roy change your class to extend `IgnoreListener` :  `public class AnnotationTransformer extends IgnoreListener implements IAnnotationTransformer`

Comment: Now it ignores the class but If I remove the ignore the test doesn't run twice when fails. it runs only once